# API server access to third party mobile applications along with User identification

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, auth0

I have to design an IAM solution for a NodeJS microservice using Auth0. Objective is to allow third party mobile application users to access this microservice.

I understand OAuth and OpenID connect solution and one simple solution is third party application accesses APIs as a client using client credentials workflow.

Solution I have to design is allowing users to login and authenticate using their Enterprise IdP connected to our Auth0 Server. So that we can implement authorization and access control at user level.

At the same time customer application needs to be kept agnostic of Auth0 service.
What I mean by it is client should not be required to add any logic in their application for accommodating our Auth0 domain like we have in first party React application. user once logged in to customer application should get access to our API also by using SSO capability. I have read some documents about configuring customer IdP with our Auth0 server acting as a SAML SP. Still I could not understand hows of it and will Auth0 create an OAuth access token in this scenario.

I realise this requires an app to intermediate between customer's mobile app and our API service. Still, I am not able to understand data flow and communication between various components.

Also, I am not sure it is a common situation or requirement? If it is is there any technical term for it? This not seem like a standard B2B scenario.

Comment: `customer needs to be kept agnostic of Auth0 service` What do you mean by that in your context? `not able to understand data flow.. between various components` This is very critical, mainly when designing a security / IdP solution. Maybe you could place more specific questions. Did you consider using an out-of-box solution? (e. g. wso2 identity server,. aws cognito,.. )

Comment: I have tried to edit question @gusto2 I have limited knowledge on this scenario so even the question is vague. End requirement is users of 3rd-party application not required to login again while 3rd-party application fetches data from our API (so SSO setup details needed) and also access toked received by our API should be for user logged in and not the third party application. Configuring their IdP (most probably Active directory) and our Auth0 servers for the same is all I need to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> have to design an IAM solution .. , I am not able to understand data flow and communication between various components ..

Before answering, the answer will points the asked specific questions, may not fit al your needs. SO is not really intended for writing tutorials or searching the documentation. Implementing an IdP (effecively a security module), one needs to do his homework and learn the details.

Maybe using an ready / out of box solution could be interesting. Using an open source IAM such as KeyCloak, WSO2IS could be a quick start. Or cloud services such as AWS Cognito, IBM AppId, Azure AD, .. could be a feasible solution too

> a client using client credentials workflow .. access toked received by our API should be for user logged in

**The `client credentials` grant is intended to authenticate only applications. That's it.**

To authenticate users, other grant type is needed. For the user authentication the most common option is the [authorization code](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-1.3.1) or the [implicit](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.2) grant. The *implicit* grant is has its weaknesses and is being replaced by the *code grant* with PKCE (just search it).

> End requirement is users of 3rd-party application not required to login again while 3rd-party application fetches data from our API .. Configuring their IdP (most probably Active directory) and our Auth0 servers for the same is all I need to understand

I see most common two options in use:

**1. federated SSO authentication**

This is the most commonly used option. The external (3rd party) IdP is configured as a "trusted" federated IdP. You often see the scenario when you have a service provider allowing to login with other IdP, often social networks (FB, Google, ...)

The login flow is as follows:

1. The client authorizes with the provider's (yours) IdP (let's call it IdP1).
2. IdP1 now acts as as Service Provider with IdP2 (IdP of the partner) and asks for the authorization (redirects the user to the IdP2).
3. User is authenticated and authorized with IdP2. If the user is already authenticated, the IdP2 doesn't need to ask the user's credentials again, this is how SSO works on this level
4. IdP2 returns to IdP1 (acting as a service provider).
5. IdP1 reads the user information (using the id_token, userinfo service - assuming using the OAuth2/OIDC protocol all the time there are other protocols too) and builds its own the user-level token. It may or may not create a local user (it is called *user provisioning*).
6. IdP1 returns to the client and the client can request a user-level token.

Then the client can call the API services with the token trusted by the API provider.

**2. Assertion Framework for OAuth Authorization Grants**

This option is built on top of the [Assertion Framework for OAuth 2.0 Client Authentication and Authorization Grants](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7521#section-9.3), it is an optional extension of the OAuth2 protocol. I call this *a token swap service*

Basically the token service could validate the access or ID token of a trusted (partner) IdP and issue its own token based on the provided user information.

---

As you see there are a lot of information and to build a secure solution you ned to make sure that all steps are properly secured (signature, expiration, issuer, validity, audience, subject domain, .. are validated). Disclaimer - as my job we implement IAM/IDM solutions and a lot can get wrong if shortcuts are taken. So you may really consider using an out of box and proven solution.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response @gusto2
I am working on this response to see exactly how to achieve the same using Auth0.

Comment: @bvnbhati yes, OAuth0 can be a good and safe option